# How do I get the Kill command on a command block to work?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I know this question has been asked a lot, but none of the answers fixed my problem. I am using education edition, by the way, so maybe that is why. Anyway, I plug in the /kill @p command to my command block. Now, I want to make it so that if somebody pushed a button it would kill them but I'm not sure how to do that. If anybody could help that would be much appreciated as I am new to the use of Command Blocks. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you are playing education edition from Bedrock edition, then you'll need to set the player's gamemode to survival (or adventure), then kill them:

```
/gamemode s @p
/kill @p
```

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Whoops! :) Good eye! I have changed the command.